# JSONB query in Rails for a key that contains an array of hashes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5, jsonb

I have a Rails 5 project with a `Page` model that has a JSONB column `content`.  So the structure looks like this (reduced to the bare minimum for the question):

```
#<Page id: 46, content: {..., "media" => [{ "resource_id" => 143, "other_key" => "value", ...}, ...], ...}>
```

How would I write a query to find all pages that have a `resource_id` of some desired number under the `media` key of the `content` JSONB column?  This was an attempt that I made which doesn't work (I think because there are other key/value pairs in each item of the array):
`Page.where("content -> 'media' @> ?", {resource_id: '143'}.to_json)`

EDIT: This works, but will only check the first hash in the media array: `Page.where("content -> 'media' -> 0 ->> 'resource_id' = ?", '143')`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using sql, this should give you all pages which have resource id 143:

```
select * from pages p where '{"resource_id": 143}' <@ ANY ( ARRAY(select jsonb_array_elements ( content -> 'media' ) from pages where id=p.id ) );
```

Postgresql has a function called ANY ([postgres docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-comparisons.html#AEN20338)) which uses the form `expression operator ANY (array)`. The left-hand expression is evaluated and compared to each element of the array using the given operator.

Since the right hand side parameter to ANY has to be an array (not a json array), we use the jsonb_array_elements method to convert the content->media json array into a set of rows which are then converted into an array by using ARRAY().

The `<@` operator checks if the expression on the right contains the expression on the left side. Ex: `'{"a": 1}'::jsonb <@ '{"b": 2, "a": 1}'::jsonb` will return true.

Comment: Thanks, that was very helpful.  Using Rails instead of straight SQL, I made up this query which gave me what I needed: 

`Page.where("'{\"resource_id\": ?}' <@ ANY (ARRAY(select jsonb_array_elements(content -> 'media')))", 143)`

Comment: How would you do this but when you'd want to search for 2 `resource_id`s ?

    ```array_select = ARRAY(select jsonb_array_elements ( content -> 'media' )

    SELECT * FROM pages p 
    WHERE '{"resource_id": 143}' <@ ANY (array_select) 
    OR '{"resource_id": 200}' <@ ANY ( ARRAY(array_select)
    FROM pages WHERE id=p.id ) );```

Like that? Or is there another way to do this?

Comment: Yes, that should work. I can't think of a better way to search for multiple resource_ids.